# fast computation for extended precision floating point for number theory application

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, hardware-acceleration, floating-point-precision

I am a graduate student in mathematics working on a research project that involves calculating the norms of algebraic integers in very high degree number fields.  Essentially, that would involve multiplying 100 more more floating point numbers together to get an integer.  I am programming in C.

The problem I am encountering is that I'm beginning to need to calculate norms which exceed 1e20 = 10^20, which exceeds both the integer and the floating point precision of my hardware (Macbook).

I could attempt to use some kind of software emulation to do extended precision, but my understanding is this is about 300x slower than hardware floating point calculation.  This would mean that the calculations I do that currently take several days would instead take several years, which isn't acceptable.

I have two questions:
Q1: Is my estimation of 300x slower for software emulation of extended precision (say to 10^36 precision, about twice the precision of hardware) unduly pessimistic?

Q2: Is I had many thousands of dollars to throw at the problem, what kind of hardware solutions might be available?

Comment: I see the downvote.  This is my first time posting here, so if this isn't an appropriate kind of question for this forum, please point me in the right direction, or let me know how I can improve the question.

Comment: I don't know about 300x. I made a 72 bit integer in 16 bit assembly with no noticeable difference but my calculations didn't require days to run.

Comment: Things that could be clearer in your question for you to receive the most helpful answer possible: 1) why are you using floating-point at all? Are some of the numbers you multiply fractions? 2) if yes, are you aware that if the denominator is not a power of two (and sometimes even if it is), the floating-point number is not the same as the rational it is supposed to represent? This sort of thing begins to be noticeable if you multiply hundreds of them to get an integer. You may not obtain the integer that you expected.

Comment: @PascalCuoq - Thanks for your help.  I am multiplying irrational numbers.  And indeed you are absolutely right about not always getting the integer I expect, which is precisely why I am looking for the extra precision.  BobbyDigital's answer though helps me.  Perhaps a double-double or quad-double implementation (rather than arbitrary precision) won't have such bad performance as I am fearing.

Comment: You might use the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/) and the [mpf_t](http://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions.html#Floating_002dpoint-Functions) type, or use the [MPFR library](http://www.mpfr.org/) on top of `GMP`.

Comment: @JohnM The only report I have heard about the quad-double implementation you are most likely referring to said that it was slower than MPFR for that particular use. Looking at the implementation, that was not too surprising. These triple-double and quad-double libraries can be really efficient when one needs slightly less than the nominal precision and smartly use this leeway to skip some normalization steps and/or lower-order terms. A generic easy-to-use quad-double library needs too many double operations to beat an integer-based multi-precision library.

Comment: @BrettHale - Thanks Brett.  I haven't yet been able to successfully get GMP working on my Mac.  But that's definitely an option I am looking at.  I'm not sure how big the performance hit would be vs. a standard hardware float multiplication operation.  Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @JohnM I use MacPorts to install Unix libraries. It takes care of dependencies, so that you would only need to tell it to install MPFR (`sudo port install mpfr`) and it would take care of installing GMP. It may bring in more dependencies than you'd like, but let it work and usually you end up with what you needed.

Comment: @PascalCuoq - that MacPorts tip worked beautifully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information you have given, I do not see any other solution than [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org). Yes, hardware floating-point give a result earlier, but it is the wrong result.

You need to pick a precision to do the computations at. Your question makes it seem like you are only concerned with the precision of the final result, but actually, accuracy is lost at each operation, and the cumulative effect of these losses must be less than 0.5 if you want to be able to decide what integer is the eventual answer. You may need to pick a precision higher than would be enough to represent the final result.

Two approaches to estimate the required precision are before-the-fact numerical analysis and interval arithmetic. I do not know anything about numerical analysis but the basics are that each irrational factor is represented by a multi-precision floating-point number that we'll assume less than 0.5 [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) away, and each multiplication may be 0.5 ULP away from the real result (of the product of the actual floating-point operands, not of what the operands are supposed to represent). People find it simpler to reason in terms of relative precision.

Interval arithmetic doubles the number of operations but provides guaranteed bounds for the real result. If there is only one integer in the computed interval, well done! Otherwise, start again with higher precision.

Finally, you ask about speed. If you really have only multiplications, it is trivial to parallelize the computation, because multiplication is associative.

Comment: Thanks Pascal.  I really appreciate your comments above about the relative merits of quad-double vs GMP.